# Should node_modules folder be included when publishing a website?

Tags: javascript, deployment, publish, node-modules, package.json

Ok, so what's the right/best approach to take when publishing a website to a web hosting service? I have a small project with some javascript dependencies and a few devDependencies. Should I include whole node_modules folder or is it best to minify them all into one js file and just upload that one?

Comment: This is a *primarily opinion-based* question because you're going to get a lot of **opinions** based of experiences, Etc.  Therefore, this question should be closed.

Comment: How is the website loading dependencies from the node_modules?

Comment: You can use webpack. It takes alle script you need automatically in one bundle.js file.

Comment: I'm familiar with webpack when playing around with React. So then I bundle them all together and link to one big js file. Thanks